# Set environment variable in OS X El Capitan so can be read by java?

Tags: java, macos

I need to set an environment variable in OS X El Capitan so it can be read by java with `System.getenv(myVar)`. How can I do it? Of course the variable must be only readable by the user who created it (and the admin probably).

Comment: Sir. i think you should ask it over [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The default shell on OS X is `bash`.

```
export FRED="Hello"
```

and then you can use something like

```
String fred = System.getenv("FRED");
System.out.println(fred);
```

Comment: I've tried, however java is unable to read it (says fred is null).

Comment: @Smeterlink It's case sensitive. "FRED" != "fred"

Answer (score 0):

I know why it happened. There's a bug in Oracle java where `SecurityManager sm = getSecurityManager();` returns always a null string (sm = null). After updating java 8.0.51 to 8.0.65 it worked perfectly. The same happens on some version of Oracle java for linux.

The affected routine is this:
`public static String getenv(String name)`